# Move to previous activity in Sequential Workflow in Windows workflow foundation?

Tags: .net, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

Hi I am very new in windows workflow foundation and creation a flow Involving moving back to previous stages(activities), But as I call previous activity within the next activity it's stop working because there is some sort of circular behavior. Can we move back to previous or any of previous stages(activities) in sequential type workflow in windows workflow foundation in .NET? Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: within a sequential workflow he only way of re-calling an activity is within a loop. I am sorry to say. If you want a 'stateful' execution a flow chart workflow might be more applicable.

Comment: @DotNetHitMan Yup, I already change that into state machine workflow after studying it and it's just work fine. Thanks and your comment clear my thinking about sequential workflow.